# difference between structure pointer and member of structure pointer

Tags: c, structure

I am declaring a structure here

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

I am creating a pointer with this declaration

```
struct node *link;
```

Is there any difference between `next` and `link` pointer or are they the same type of pointer?

Comment: Of course, they are of the same *data type*. You declared them so!! They both point to address of an data type `struct node`.

Comment: What makes you think there iks a difference ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I feel like a difference because next pointer is declared when the structure is not completely defined and link pointer is declared when the structure is completely defined

Comment: @kapil These are two different ways to declare struct pointer and other than that there is no difference.

Comment: @kapil when you declare `struct node *next`, `struct node`is not yet completely defined, but we only declare a _pointer_ and therefore the compiler doesn't need to know the complete definition of `struct node`, it only needts to know that the `struct node` exists.

Comment: @MichaelWalz this means that both the pointers are same isn't it

Comment: @kapil No, it's two different pointers, their _type_ is the same. It's just as if you declare `ìnt a; int b;`  `a` and `b` are different, but they have the same type.

Comment: @MichaelWalz oh yeah i mean to say the same sorry, thanks for clearing my doubt :")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *link
```

*next and *link are both pointers, so their size will be the same. The data type they point to is the same, the structure `node`. But they are quite different:

```
struct node *p = malloc(sizeof (node)); //allocate memory for a new node

//now, p will point to an address.
//p->next is still un-initilized, so we have to assign it an address 

p->next = NULL; 

p, and p->next point to different addressess
```

So the two pointers are different and exist independently of each other. In fact, *link does not even have to be a pointer, you can statically allocate memory for a node:

```
struct node p;
p.next=NULL
```

Or you can add other pointers to node to the node structure for more complex data structures like trees or double linked lists:

```
struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node* next;
   struct node* prev;
}
```

Comment: you are printing the address of node* and node->data. Of course they will be the same because the data is the first member of the strucure. And even if your structure had only node*  members node* and node->memberX would still be different pointers

Answer (score 1):

There is one difference.

The link pointer can have an initial value but next pointer cannot have an initial value and the reason is:

Whenever we declare a structure,we are declaring a new type and not a new variable.

So

```
struct node *link=NULL;
```

is allowed while

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next=NULL;
};
```

is NOT allowed.

Comment: the answer does not really address the question and is quite misleading. That is not the difference between the two pointer!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next; // line 1
};

struct node *link; // line 2
```

line 1 is known as self referential structure and line 2 is just a pointer variable of given structure.
In linked list self referential structure is used, because we want all the nodes of same type. Suppose, if you declare `struct node *p = malloc(sizeof (node));`
Here, p creates some space and that space is divided in two parts 1. int data 2. *next .
means one portion has data and other portion has address of next node.